# Fixing aliases for hidden files

Tags: filesystem, alias, invisible-files

Had to migrate to a new Mac and all of the aliases I have for hidden files are broken. When I try to navigate to the original file when I click "fix alias", I can't see the file in question in the navigation window despite having hidden files set to visible.

How do I fix all these broken aliases?

Comment: How certain are you that the files exist? Can you see them normally in Finder with 'show hidden' enabled? How was the migration done?

Comment: Yes, I can see them clearly in the Finder if I navigate to them. They just aren't visible when the file selection window opens.

Comment: hmm.. I just realised on Mojave, that setting 'show invisibles' doesn't also show in file-picker dialogs. Hit Cmd/shift/period again in the dialog. They seem to toggle independently.

Comment: That displayed the hidden files, but when I select the correct files to link the aliases to I always get "An unexpected error occurred (error code -36)."

Comment: That's basically a file not found error. Maybe try unhiding the files, or just make new aliases instead.

Comment: These are all dot files, so I'll have to just manually remake all the aliases it seems.